# Writing in several columns of a CSV file at the same time

Tags: python, csv

For writing the names of the files inside a csv file I use the following script:

```
import csv
import os

searchDirPath = '/mnt'
searchFileExt = '.mp4'


with open('/root/val_25.csv', 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchDirPath):
        for file in files:
            searchResults =[]
            if file.endswith(".mp4"):
             
             full_address = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, file))
             path_components = full_address.split(os.sep)
             Label= path_components[6]   # label name
             
             
             searchResults.append(str(full_address))

             print(os.path.join(root, file))
             
             writer.writerow(searchResults)
```

The mentioned script wrtie in tbe rows in the first column. I need to write the `Label` variable in the second column in front of each name. In other words, I need to write the name of the files (as the current script does) and at the same time, I need to write the `Label` in the second column in front of that written name.
How I can do that?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're missing but you should add everything you want in your row to your `searchResults` list. So e.g. add another `searchResults.append` call....

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then ... do that?

```
import csv
import os

searchDirPath = '/mnt'
searchFileExt = '.mp4'

with open('/root/val_25.csv', 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchDirPath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".mp4"):             
                full_address = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, file))
                label = full_address.split(os.sep)[6]
                print(os.path.join(root, file))             
                writer.writerow([label, full_address])
```

I somewhat simplified redundancies in the code.

Comment: The hard-coding of the label to always be the sixth component looks like a possible bug, but I can't guess how you have organized your files. Perhaps ask a new question with more details if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you break up your problem into two parts:

1. get the list of all the files you want to write to the CSV
2. write the CSV

You might also consider using glob instead of trying to walk the tree yourself, I cannot guarantee identical ordering between glob and walk, but in this simple example, the orders match:

```
- mnt
 - dir_1
  - dir_3
     file7.mp4
    file4.mp4
 - dir_2
  - dir_4
     file8.mp4
    file6.mp4
   file2.mp4
```

```py
import glob
import os

globbed_files = list(glob.glob("mnt/**/*.mp4", recursive=True))

walked_files: list[str] = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("mnt"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp4"):
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            walked_files.append(full_path)


print(f"Globbed: {globbed_files}")
print(f"Walked:  {walked_files}")
```

```py
Globbed: [
    'mnt/fileA.mp4', 'mnt/dir_2/fileB.mp4', 'mnt/dir_2/dir_4/fileC.mp4', 'mnt/dir_1/fileD.mp4', 'mnt/dir_1/dir_3/fileE.mp4'
]
Walked:  [
    'mnt/fileA.mp4', 'mnt/dir_2/fileB.mp4', 'mnt/dir_2/dir_4/fileC.mp4', 'mnt/dir_1/fileD.mp4', 'mnt/dir_1/dir_3/fileE.mp4'
]
```

After that, process the results and write to the CSV (you don't need "w+", that's for simultaneous reading and writing... I see you just needing to write, here):

```py
import csv
from os.path import normpath

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Full path", "Name", "Label"])

    for full_path in globbed_files:  # or, walked_files
        components = normpath(full_path).split(os.sep)
        name = components[-1]
        label = components[-2]  # your real criteria for label; this just gets the parent's name
        writer.writerow([full_path, name, label])
```

```
| Full path                 | Name      | Label |
|---------------------------|-----------|-------|
| mnt/fileA.mp4             | fileA.mp4 | mnt   |
| mnt/dir_2/fileB.mp4       | fileB.mp4 | dir_2 |
| mnt/dir_2/dir_4/fileC.mp4 | fileC.mp4 | dir_4 |
| mnt/dir_1/fileD.mp4       | fileD.mp4 | dir_1 |
| mnt/dir_1/dir_3/fileE.mp4 | fileE.mp4 | dir_3 |
```